# Is it possible to do paging with JoinSqlBuilder?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a pretty normal join that I create via JoinSqlBuilder

```
var joinSqlBuilder = new JoinSqlBuilder<ProductWithManufacturer, Product>()
                    .Join<Product, Manufacturer>(sourceColumn: p => p.ManufacturerId,
                                                 destinationColumn: mf => mf.Id,
                                                 sourceTableColumnSelection: p => new { ProductId = p.Id, ProductName = p.Name },
                                                 destinationTableColumnSelection: m => new { ManufacturerId = m.Id, ManufacturerName = m.Name })
```

Of course, the join created by this could potentially return a lot of rows, so I want to use paging - preferably on the server-side. However, I cannot find anything in the JoinSqlBuilder which would let me do this? Am I missing something or does JoinSqlBuilder not have support for this (yet)?

Comment: New `Limit`, `Skip` and `Offset` API's [are now available](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/f45700ef5c62edc28f61261549db1070189913eb) on JoinSqlBuilder in [v4.0.22 that's now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)

Comment: @mythz Thank you, you truly are amazing! :)

Comment: np :) let me know if there are any issues with it in the forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using MS SQL Server I think the following will work.

```
var sql = joinSqlBuilder.ToSql();
var data = this.Select<ProductWithManufacturer>(
                 q => q.Select(sql)
                       .Limit(skip,rows)
           );
```

If you are working with MS SQL Server, it will most likely blow up on you. I am working to merge a more elegant solution similar to this into JoinSqlBuilder. The following is a quick and dirty method to accomplish what you want.

I created the following extension class:

```
public static class Extension
{

    private static string ToSqlWithPaging<TResult, TTarget>(
        this JoinSqlBuilder<TResult, TTarget> bldr,
        string orderColumnName,
        int limit,
        int skip)
    {
        var sql = bldr.ToSql();

        return string.Format(@"
                 SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [{0}]) As RowNum, *
                        FROM (
                            {1}
                            )as InnerResult
                        )as RowConstrainedResult
                    WHERE RowNum > {2} AND RowNum <= {3}
            ", orderColumnName, sql, skip, skip + limit);
    }

    public static string ToSqlWithPaging<TResult, TTarget>(
        this JoinSqlBuilder<TResult, TTarget> bldr,
        Expression<Func<TResult, object>> orderSelector,
        int limit,
        int skip)
    {

        var member = orderSelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "TResult selector refers to a non member."
                );

        var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "TResult selector refers to a field, it must be a property."
                );

        var orderSelectorName = propInfo.Name;

        return ToSqlWithPaging(bldr, orderSelectorName, limit, skip);
    }
}
```

It is applied as follows:

```
List<Entity> GetAllEntities(int limit, int skip) 
{
   var bldr = GetJoinSqlBuilderFor<Entity>();
   var sql = bldr.ToSqlWithPaging(
                     entity => entity.Id,
                     limit,
                     skip);
   return this.Db.Select<Entity>(sql);
}
```

Comment: Sadly I am working with MSSQL so I can't take the easy way out :( Your extension method seems to work pretty good though, so I think I'll use that for now :) Thanks a lot!